# CSS works with FF and IE, but not Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, stylesheet, font-size

I know this is probably one simple mistake I'm missing, but a second set of eyes would be great. The following HTML and CSS is connecting on Firefox and IE, but not Chrome. I'm testing it with the font size. It is like Chrome is ignoring the CSS.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Put A Title Here Later</title>
  <meta name="description" content="What is this about?">
  <meta name="author" content="My Name">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

Comment: You're missing code here. The code you provided looks the same in all three browsers. Also, I'm not sure what the question is. http://jsfiddle.net/9TynE/

Comment: Not working means what? What's happening? Does chrome show you font-size more than 100???

Comment: Try using a CSS Reset. However, I don't think that this is the solution. nevertheless, you should really use one.

Comment: I recommend Eric Meyer's CSS Reset

Comment: I would also suggest checking out [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: IE and Firefox are recognizing the stylesheet and changing the font-size. Chrome seems to be ignoring that there is a CSS file though.

Comment: @user2572864 Without seeing the code there's no way we can help you. Did you look at my jsfiddle? Go to it, replicate your problem in it, save it and then link the new url back here. Then we can see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome likes to cache stylesheets. That's the only thing I think would be different here given the code provided. When you have this page loaded in Chrome, try pressing Ctr + Shift + R for a hard reload.

If that doesn't work, press F12 to open the inspector, then go back to your main browser window and click and hold the reload button until a sub menu pops up. From there select "Empty Cache and Hard Reload".

Also, be sure that you have actually typed this CSS and not copy and pasted it. It's rare, but I have seen a copy-and-paste introduce hidden characters that caused strange browser errors.